# Python/Pydantic - using a list with json objects

Tags: python, json, pydantic

I have a working model to receive a `json` data set using `pydantic`.  The model data set looks like this:

```
data = {'thing_number': 123, 
        'thing_description': 'duck',
        'thing_amount': 4.56}
```

What I would like to do is have a list of `json` files as the data set and be able to validate them.  Ultimately the list will be converted to records in `pandas` for further processing.  My goal is to validate an arbitrarily long list of `json` entries that looks something like this:

```
bigger_data = [{'thing_number': 123, 
                'thing_description': 'duck',
                'thing_amount': 4.56}, 
               {'thing_number': 456, 
                'thing_description': 'cow',
                'thing_amount': 7.89}]
```

The basic setup I have now is as follows.  Note that adding the `class ItemList` is part of the attempt to get the arbitrary length to work.

```
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic.schema import schema
import json

class Item(BaseModel):
    thing_number: int
    thing_description: str
    thing_amount: float

class ItemList(BaseModel):
    each_item: List[Item]
```

The basic code will then produce what I think I'm looking for in an array object that will take `Item` objects.

```
item_schema = schema([ItemList])
print(json.dumps(item_schema, indent=2)) 

    {
      "definitions": {
        "Item": {
          "title": "Item",
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "thing_number": {
              "title": "Thing_Number",
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "thing_description": {
              "title": "Thing_Description",
              "type": "string"
            },
            "thing_amount": {
              "title": "Thing_Amount",
              "type": "number"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "thing_number",
            "thing_description",
            "thing_amount"
          ]
        },
        "ItemList": {
          "title": "ItemList",
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "each_item": {
              "title": "Each_Item",
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/Item"
              }
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "each_item"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

The setup works on a singe json item being passed:

```
item = Item(**data)                                                      

print(item)

Item thing_number=123 thing_description='duck' thing_amount=4.56
```

But when I try and pass the single item into the `ItemList` model it returns an error:

```
item_list = ItemList(**data)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValidationError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-94-48efd56e7b6c> in <module>
----> 1 item_list = ItemList(**data)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pydantic/main.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pydantic/main.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so in pydantic.main.validate_model()

ValidationError: 1 validation error for ItemList
each_item
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

I've also tried passing `bigger_data` into the array thinking that it would need to start as a list.  that also returns an error - - Although, I at least have a better understanding of the dictionary error I can't figure out how to resolve.

```
item_list2 = ItemList(**data_big)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-100-8fe9a5414bd6> in <module>
----> 1 item_list2 = ItemList(**data_big)

TypeError: MetaModel object argument after ** must be a mapping, not list
```

Thanks.

**Other Things I've Tried**

I've tried passing the data into the specific key with a little more luck (maybe?).

```
item_list2 = ItemList(each_item=data_big)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValidationError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-111-07e5c12bf8b4> in <module>
----> 1 item_list2 = ItemList(each_item=data_big)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pydantic/main.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pydantic/main.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so in pydantic.main.validate_model()

ValidationError: 6 validation errors for ItemList
each_item -> 0 -> thing_number
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
each_item -> 0 -> thing_description
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
each_item -> 0 -> thing_amount
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
each_item -> 1 -> thing_number
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
each_item -> 1 -> thing_description
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
each_item -> 1 -> thing_amount
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel
import json


class Item(BaseModel):
    thing_number: int
    thing_description: str
    thing_amount: float


class ItemList(BaseModel):
    each_item: List[Item]
```

Base on your code with each_item as a List of Item

```
a_duck = Item(thing_number=123, thing_description="duck", thing_amount=4.56)
print(a_duck.json())

a_list = ItemList(each_item=[a_duck])

print(a_list.json())
```

Generate the following output:

```
{"thing_number": 123, "thing_description": "duck", "thing_amount": 4.56}
{"each_item": [{"thing_number": 123, "thing_description": "duck", "thing_amount": 4.56}]}
```

using these as "entry json":

```
a_json_duck = {"thing_number": 123, "thing_description": "duck", "thing_amount": 4.56}
a_json_list = {
    "each_item": [
        {"thing_number": 123, "thing_description": "duck", "thing_amount": 4.56}
    ]
}

print(Item(**a_json_duck))
print(ItemList(**a_json_list))
```

Work just fine and generates:

```
Item thing_number=123 thing_description='duck' thing_amount=4.56
ItemList each_item=[<Item thing_number=123 thing_description='duck' thing_amount=4.56>]
```

We are just left with the only datas:

```
just_datas = [
    {"thing_number": 123, "thing_description": "duck", "thing_amount": 4.56},
    {"thing_number": 456, "thing_description": "cow", "thing_amount": 7.89},
]
item_list = ItemList(each_item=just_datas)
print(item_list)
print(type(item_list.each_item[1]))
print(item_list.each_item[1])
```

Those works as expected:

```
ItemList each_item=[<Item thing_number=123 thing_description='duck'thing_amount=4.56>,<Item thin…
<class '__main__.Item'>
Item thing_number=456 thing_description='cow' thing_amount=7.89
```

So in case i'm missing something the pydantic librairy works as expected.

My pydantic version : 0.30 python 3.7.4

Reading from a lookalike file:

```
json_data_file = """[
{"thing_number": 123, "thing_description": "duck", "thing_amount": 4.56},
{"thing_number": 456, "thing_description": "cow", "thing_amount": 7.89}]"""

from io import StringIO
item_list2 = ItemList(each_item=json.load(StringIO(json_data_file)))
```

Work also fine.

Comment: I spent hours thinking the issue was the class/object structure - - not how i was loading the information.  Works perfect.  Thanks.

Answer (score 27):

To avoid having `"each_item"` in the `ItemList`, you can use the [`__root__`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#custom-root-types) Pydantic keyword:

```
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Item(BaseModel):
    thing_number: int
    thing_description: str
    thing_amount: float

class ItemList(BaseModel):
    __root__: List[Item]    # ⯇-- __root__
```

To build the `item_list`:

```py
just_data = [
    {"thing_number": 123, "thing_description": "duck", "thing_amount": 4.56},
    {"thing_number": 456, "thing_description": "cow", "thing_amount": 7.89},
]
item_list = ItemList(__root__=just_data)

a_json_duck = {"thing_number": 123, "thing_description": "duck", "thing_amount": 4.56}
item_list.__root__.append(a_json_duck)
```

The web-frameworks supporting Pydantic often jsonify such `ItemList` as a JSON array without intermediate `__root__` keyword.

Comment: For my own understanding, does the `__root__` effectively change the 'root' character of the `ItemList` to those item in `Item`?  Whereas, using `each_item` effectively creates a thing inside `ItemList`?  Thanks.

Comment: The [docs](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#custom-root-types) lists this as a use case, so I prefer this, _although_ it feels slighly un-pythonic to ask users to use `__root__` keyword. Advantage of this method over the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58081073/2670584) is that `ItemList.json()` returns the expected JSON structure.

Comment: Unfortunately, when appending items to the __root__ (as done at the end of this answer), there is no validation of these items. They are simply appended. If (like in your case), the items in the list are pydantic models that might require validation, you need to trigger this yourself (e.g. using Item.validate(...)).

Comment: For information, if you want to iterate over the `__root__` list or access items by an index -- you have to implement `__iter__` and `__getitem__` methods in the class.

Answer (score 27):

The following also works, and does not require a root type.

To convert from a `List[dict]` to a `List[Item]`:

```
items = parse_obj_as(List[Item], bigger_data)
```

To convert from JSON `str` to a `List[Item]`:

```
items = parse_raw_as(List[Item], bigger_data_json)
```

To convert from a `List[Item]` to a JSON `str`:

```
from pydantic.json import pydantic_encoder

bigger_data_json = json.dumps(items, default=pydantic_encoder)
```

or with a custom encoder:

```
from pydantic.json import pydantic_encoder

def custom_encoder(**kwargs):
    def base_encoder(obj):
        if isinstance(obj, BaseModel):
            return obj.dict(**kwargs)
        else:
            return pydantic_encoder(obj)
    return base_encoder


bigger_data_json = json.dumps(items, default=custom_encoder(by_alias=True))
```

Comment: I found this really useful. For others, the import for `pydantic_encoder` is: `from pydantic.json import pydantic_encoder` .

Comment: This saved the day for me. It was exactly what I needed, without doing this, I received a non-serializable datamodel error.

Comment: Thanks! This deserves to be documented more clearly. The case of returning a simple list of pydantic types is pretty common …

Answer (score 1):

what did the trick for me was `fastapi.encoders.jsonable_encoder` (take a look at https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/encoder/)

So in your case I have appended the "single" items to a list `result` i.e. `result.append(Item(thing_number=123, thing_description="duck", thing_amount=4.56))`

and finally `fastapi.JSONResponse(content=fastapi.encoders.jsonable_encoder(result))`

Comment: The question is asked in a Pydantic context. Not everyone that uses pydantic uses it in a FastAPI context...